# Count Number of Elements JavaScript

Tags: javascript, frontend

I'm working on an on-boarding flow where users click a follow button and then a class of 'gray' is added to the button. Once there are 3 buttons with a class of 'gray', I want to run a function in JavaScript. How can I do this? Here's the JavaScript code to add the classes to the buttons:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".join-5 a").click(function() {
       var i = $(this).attr("id");
       $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/groups/" + i + "/join",
          success: function() {
            $(".join-5").html("<a href='#' class='btn btn-default gray'>Joined</a>");
          }
       })
     })
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use length, you can put this after you build your gray element in the callback:

```
if($('.gray').length == 3) {
  // do something
}
```

---

So the full thing should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".join-5 a").click(function() {
       var i = $(this).attr("id");
       $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/groups/" + i + "/join",
          success: function() {
            $(".join-5").html("<a href='#' class='btn btn-default gray'>Joined</a>");
            if($('.gray').length == 3) {
                // do something
            }
          }
       })
     })
 });
```

Of course, you can adjust the selector if you need to target gray buttons within a specific container.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting this error: Uncaight SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Sorry, extra bracket... Updated it.